# Let JBoss 5.1 send Accept-Encoding: gzip with JAX-WS

Tags: jboss, jax-ws, gzip

I have a JBoss 5.1.1 server which needs to send SOAP messages to an outside party. This party has provided some WSDL files that I have used to generate the WebService code from. This is all working just fine.

However, now I need to enable GZIP support for the SOAP messages. In theory, it's as simple as adding an "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" header to the SOAP requests' HTTP messages. The outside party will then send the response with GZIP encoding. However, I haven't found a way to make JBoss add that header. I'm hoping someone around here can tell me how to do that.

Comment: I found [this site](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jitu/archive/2007/07/jaxws_ri_and_co.html) which shows exactly how to add headers to my SOAP messages. Now all I need to do is get HttpContentDecompressor of Netty or something similar to work, so response messages are parsed correctly. Right now I'm getting EOFExceptions because JBoss doesn't know that it must decompress the contents.